# Use info from a stored procedure to rename the columns of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a listbox whose contents are generated by a stored procedure.  Works perfectly.

```
private void PasswordTabTasks()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
    conn.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("EXEC GetPasswordTabNames", conn);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    lbPasswordTabs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    lbPasswordTabs.DisplayMember = "TabName";
    lbPasswordTabs.ValueMember = "ID";
    conn.Close();            
}
```

However, I want to use the selected item of this listbox (first item in table row is listbox.DisplayMember, next 3 items I want to be column name in DGV.)  Essentially I want to create dynamic DGV column names via textboxes (Got all text boxes to insert data properly into Table, just need help recalling the next 3 columns and converting them to DGV headers/column names). I'm sorry I do not have any sample code to go from at this point.  Not even sure of the correct terminology I'm looking for here?  Possibly "Stored procedure to string"?

Any hints or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

I realize the code I'm looking for will go in the

```
private void lbPasswordTabs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here
}
```

Comment: As posted this question doesn't make any sense at all. I can't even begin to understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve... My magic crystall ball tells me, that you want to read some values of your listbox or some column names of the datasource... I'd suggest to set a stop mark on conn.Close. When the execution is paused, mark `ds.Tables[0]` and press `shift + F9`. This will allow you to examine the returned table. Look at the `.Rows` and at the `.Columns` collection.

Comment: Try to give us an *explicit example* of data returned and the result that you want in your DGV, so that we can figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As stated, I know what I'm trying to accomplish, but not exactly sure the correct terminology for it. What I'm trying to do is take the results of a stored procedure, and use those results to name column headers in a DGV. Imagine you have a table. 5 columns. Column 1 stores the values that the listbox is listing, columns 2-5 are storing the values I want to name the headers at the top of the columns in the DGV when the text from column 1 is selected in the listbox.